# How can I boost performance in Rome 2?

Tags: technical-issues, rome-2-total-war

My machine is great, and runs other games with no issues, but Rome 2 is a tough nut to crack! There are so many arcane graphical options I don't know where to start.

Does anyone have any strategies for optimally boosting frame rates or reducing load/wait times without losing too much graphical quality?

Comment: I don't have the game, but see screecaps of the advanced options: the first items to go to are Shadows = huge hit; SSAO = huge hit. My personal preference is to back down on resolution before reducing other settings.
    
    Anti-aliasing = big hit

Comment: Rome 2 is known for having poor performance on some high end machines and Creative Assembly promised to fix that. I know that on my high end rig, the framerate sometimes drops from 30-60 FPS to less than 3 FPS because the game apparently requires more than the 2 GB VRAM shipped with my GTX 680 in some conditions (using Extreme preset). CA also  recommends turning the Vegetation alpha off unless your rig is *really* powerful.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah at the moment Shogun 2 looks so much better then Rome 2 in terms of graphics atm on my gaming rig. And it drops frames at times :/

Answer (score 1):

I found that switching to DX11 gave me a significant increase in performance over DX9, as have some other users. I also turn off shadows (they look terrible on any middle quality)

Comment: How do you "switch" to DX11? I'm using Shader Model 5, so that must mean the game is already running in DX11 mode, no?

Comment: Yeah the switch between SM3 and SM5 is equivilent to switching DX versions. You are already in DX11 so it doesn't apply to you in particular